# Is iOS 7 Mobile Safari throttling touchmove events

Tags: iphone, backbone.js, coffeescript, touch, ios7

I'm building a web application that is accessed using mobile safari.

I am seeing significantly less frequent position updates from the touchmove event after upgrading to iOS7. Can someone confirm that this event has been throttled, preferably with a link to an article, explanation, or bug report?

The code I use is very simple--it just follows `touchmove` and uses that position to update the height of a div. This is used to create a custom slider/fill bar UI.

```
View = Backbone.View.extend
  events:
    touchmove:  'onDragMove'
  onDragMove: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    @_follow event
  _follow: (event) ->
    @windowHeight = @windowHeight || $(window).height() # Don't calculate window height every drag increment :)
    @personHeight = @personHeight || @$el.height()
    @$fill =        @$fill || @$(_fillSel)
    touch = event.originalEvent.touches[0] || event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0]
    y = touch.pageY
    height = @windowHeight - y
    percentage = Math.round height / @personHeight * 100
    percentage = @_boundValue percentage
    @$fill.css height: height
    percentage
```

Before updating, this was fluid and responsive. After updating, there is a delay in updating the position. Looks to me like the event was debounced or throttled by Apple.

Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: I can confirm that we are experiencing similar issues with iOS 7 with a mobile safari app.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check it on 7.1 beta? We had problems with touchmove and canvas interaction with 7.0 - 7.0.4, which disappeared with 7.1 beta.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using a javascript scrolling implementation.

I've found a solution using some CSS provided in a similar question :-) :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19061390/2553142