# `touchmove` events won't fire on Mobile Safari?

Tags: jquery, iphone, safari

Mobile Safari will not register `touchmove` events! `touchstart` and `touchend` both work as expected, but `touchmove` refuses to fire.

```
$("#Element").on({
    "touchmove" : function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("touch move!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in CSS. To give the scrolling on my site a smoother feel, I added:

```
html, body {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Once I commented that out, `touchmove` fired correctly.